# Pointiness not working in 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

I faced a weird issue: geometry->pointiness node on my subdivided cube shows up a constant value all over the mesh. Is it a bug or me doing something wrong?[image: problem]

Here's the topology of the cube:[image: topology]

Also tried with Suzanne, however effect remains the same. Blender version: 2.80.45

Comment: additionally I tried tweaking the value with ramp but it changed nothing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using Eevee, the pointiness output only works in cycles atm.

[image]

**Workaround for Edge Highlighting:**

There is a way to get the same or similar result "pointiness" gives you. The function is called "dirty vertex colors" and its avaiable in the vertex paint mode.

[image]

[image]
You can play around with the settings here, depending on the mesh of yours some work better, others do not, but you can probably find a tutorial for that.

[image]

**Note: Booth Pointiness and Dirty Vertex Colors are dependent on the Geometry-Resolution, i've just added a Bevel modifier with 3 Segments and applied it.**

Another method of doing this, would be, to bake your pointiness colors as a texture and use them in your eevee shader.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/I2cTDzt.png it's cycles. That's strange as it works for you

Comment: nvm, needed to change to rendered mode and it shows up

Comment: ah yeah, the LookDev view in Cycles is Eevee, so i assumed that you were in Eevee, well i got that wrong^^. glad its working now for you!

Comment: hi, Is there any alternative for evee? I want to reduce the render time so I am using evee.

Comment: Yes, you can, i'll edit my answer on the top with the alternative way..